# If I have two 61.87(n)/(p) student solo endorsements, can I pick which one to operate under?

Tags: ppl, logbook-endorsements, solo-flight

**The backstory:**

I am working on my US PPL. I started my training with Mr. D, and got most of what I needed for my solo with him except perfecting my landings. Mr. D felt he was having trouble helping me get my landings down, so he handed my off to Mr. J. I worked on landings with Mr. J and he felt I was ready to solo. We planned a day, but a day before, Mr. J had a family emergency that had him out of town for 2 weeks, so he handed my solo off to Mr. D.

Mr. D and I flew and he felt I was ready, so he signed me off for a 61.87(c) endorsement and I did a solo flight. We took a break (lunch) and then he signed me off for a 61.87(n) endorsement and I did another supervised solo.

On that second solo flight, the last landing was a flatish bounce that I think rattled me (figuratively & mentally) a bit. I ended up going around 3 times, but did land it successfully on that 3rd try. The next day the plane went into annual, which took 3 weeks.

So while I legally could go fly solo at that point, I then spent the next month training more landings with Mr. J. I now feel *much* more ready personally and have a feel for when to add power and what that will do while landing. Mr. J says he wants to do a solo flight in the next week, signing off a 61.87(p) endorsement as part of that.

The 61.87(n) endorsement Mr. D gave me still has a month and a half left. It states a limitation of 5 miles or greater visibility, no more than 8 knots direct crosswind. Mr. J has stated that his endorsement will come with a limitation of "written permission the day of the flight" - I will have to text and get permission before each flight.

One of the challenges of my flight training has been my work schedule not always been predictable, and one of the things I have been looking forward to with a solo endorsement is more flexibility schedule wise. I have nothing against asking a CFI for advice regarding a go/no go decision on a particular day, but if they are not available (camping as it usually is with Mr. J) I would like to be able to fly on days where the weather is clearly good. My general thought is if I have a hole open up in my (and the club plane's) schedule, I would text Mr. J, do a weather brief, go preflight the plane, and if I hadn't heard back, decide on my own, with an extra margin of "no go" bias for safety.

**The question(s):**
If I have two 61.87(n)/(p) student solo endorsements for overlapping time periods, can I pick which one to operate under or am I only allowed to operate by the most recent one? If I am only allowed to operate under the most recent, would I be unwise or unsafe to request to use my current endorsement until it expires? Does Mr. J have to be the one to have signed the most recent 61.87(n)/(p) endorsement to endorse further things, like cross country flights?

Comment: This is just a grown up version of "mom said no, but dad said yes." You really ought to be addressing this topic with your instructors. Regardless of any legal answer, maintaining a positive working relationship with each should guide your actions in this matter. That can only come from you getting them both on the same page WRT your training progress and solo privileges. Nothing good can come from playing one against the other.